# Lógica de modelagem de categorias em um e-commerce

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, lógica

Estou com um projeto de criar um e-commerce, no qual a minha duvida se refere a modelagem das tabelas:

> Categoria(RAIZ)>sub-categorias>sub-categorias da sub-categoria.

Como deveria ser essas tabelas, sendo que um produto podem estar dentro de farias categorias(raiz), e nelas podem estar também em sub-categorias. As tabelas teriam que ficar aptas para funcionar igual ao print abaixo, segue:
[image: Exemplo de menu existente em um e-commerce, assim que terei que fazer]

> Segue abaixo um exemplo do que fiz:
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Categorias com Sub-Categorias, eu costumo fazer uma única tabela. Nessa tabela eu adiciono um campo  `idCategoriaPai`.

Quando for fazer um cadastro de categoria deixo esse campo `null`. Quando vou cadastrar uma sub-categoria, preencho esse campo com o `id` da categoria pai.

Se este campo estiver preenchido, a categoria é uma sub-categoria. Se não estiver, a categoria é a categoria raiz.

Se você precisar retornar o nome de todas as categorias pai da sua sub-categoria é só fazer uma função recursiva.

Desta forma, você consegue fazer vários níveis de sub-categorias.

Não sei se é a melhor forma, mas é a forma que costumo trabalhar.

Comment: iria falar a mesma coisa  :)

Comment: roberto, editei minha pergunta e adicionei mais uma imagem, sendo ela referencia do seu exemplo, seria isso?

Comment: No meu ponto de vista você nem precisa dessa tabela `categorias_has_produtos`. O campo `Categorias_id` pode estar direto na tabela `Produtos`. Isso porque, a relação de categoria e produto é `1-1`, se fosse `1-N` ai sim essa terceira tabela seria necessária.

Comment: mas esse é o caso, o produto pode estar em mais de uma categoria ao mesmo tempo, dai seria necessário a tabela **categorias_has_produtos**, correto?

Comment: Ah sim, então é necessário sim essa terceira tabela.

Comment: @RobertoFagundes, obrigado pela sua ajuda!